# Angular: Problema con los input type="date" y ngModel

Tags: html, angular, angular6, input-type

Al cargar la página no me muestra el valor que tiene mi variable Date (sala.fechaVigencia), es como si estuviera vacía. Solo me pasa con los input type="date", con text y number no tengo problema.

Esta etiqueta esta dentro de un formulario

```
<input type="date" name="inputVigencia" [(ngModel)]="sala.fechaVigencia" class="form-control"/>
```

Comprobé con un console.log() y me muestra su valor (se que no está vacía), también me lo cambia cuando le asigno un valor con el input.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Sala } from '../../shared/model/sala';
import { SalaService } from '../../shared/service/sala.service';
import { TipoSala } from '../../shared/model/tipoSala';
import { TipoSalasService } from '../../shared/service/tipo-salas.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-detalle-sala',
templateUrl: './detalle-sala.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./detalle-sala.component.css']
})
export class DetalleSalaComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private salasService: SalaService,
    private tipoSalasService: TipoSalasService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
) { }

@Input() sala: Sala;

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let codigo = params.codigo;

        this.salasService.ObtenerPorCodigo(codigo)
            .then((data) => {
                this.sala = data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Que formato le estas pasando?

Comment: puedes mostrar tu ts?

Comment: Obtengo las fechas de una api en .NET en formato UTC y el parse lo hago: fecha = new Date(fecha)

Answer (score 0):

Intente algo asi,

```
<input type="date" id="inputVigencia" [(ngModel)]="sala.fechaVigencia" class="form-control"/>
```

Claves:

ngModel in angularX(2..9) es valido solo si el FormsModule ha sido incluido en su AppModule.

ng-model es una sintaxis incorrecta.
square braces(Llaves) [..] refiere a el binding de la propiedad.
circle braces(Parentesis) (..) refiere al binding del evento.

cuando los dos binding se combinan se le llama two way binding(Binding en ambas direcciones), tambien llamado banana box.

Para resolver el error siga estos pasos.

Paso 1: Importe FormsModule

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
```

Paso 2: Agregue el modulo al arreglo de imports en AppModule:

```
 imports :[ ... , FormsModule ]
```

Paso 3: Agregue su codigo

```
<input type="date" id="inputVigencia" [(ngModel)]="sala.fechaVigencia" class="form-control"/>
```

Nota: El two way binding puede ser manejado de forma independiete como le muestro a continuacion.

```
<input type="date" id="inputVigencia" [ngModel]="sala.fechaVigencia" 
(ngModelChange)="valorCambio($event)
class="form-control"/>
```

*.ts file

```
valorCambio(value){
   console.log("nuevo valor:" + value)
}
```

Buena suerte!

Comment: Utilizo name y no id porque sino me tira un error en el cual me dice que debo asignar un name.
Aplique tus recomendaciones y todo sigue igual.

Comment: Para poder ayudar voy a necesitar ver su codigo TS, porque algo tiene que estar afectando el binding, y con la informacion que tengo no voy a poder ver lo que es

Comment: ahí publique mi ts.
FormsModule está importado en appmodule

Comment: Si usted observa en la linea 4 tiene import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms', esto solo se necesita en el AppModule, no en la definicion del componente. Si revisa su module puede que vea que no tiene esto definido, porque definitivamente en el componente no hace nada.

Comment: eso ignóralo, lo agregue a modo de prueba. ya lo borre. Está en AppModule.

Comment: vea este ejemplo, https://stackblitz.com/angular/xeqlxnpbndy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: me falto aclarar que el problema solo me pasa con los input type="date". Con el resto no tengo problema, ya sea text o number

Answer (score 0):

Intenta declarar el objeto `sala` en lugar de `@Input`, como `public` y asegúrate que recibes un valor fecha en el objeto

Answer (score 0):

No me preguntes por qué, porque no lo sé pero el error existe y la solución que yo encontre alguna vez fue esta

```
// .ts
varDate = new Date();

// html
//ejemplo type="date"
<input type="date" [ngModel] ="varDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="varDate = $event">
// ejemplo type="datetime-local"
<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel] ="varDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="varDate = $event">
```

solo tendrías que cambiar `varDate` por `sala.fechaVigencia`